# How to Fill NA With text

Tags: r, replace, na

I want to fill a variable that is currently filled with NA, with "fem" text. See below:

[image]

I have tried `merge`, `coalesce`, and some other ways but I am new to R and was probably doing those wrong. I just need help to fill this column ("female") with "fem".

Comment: `df$female[is.na(df$female)] <- "fem"`?

Comment: If the variable is a character type variable, then just use:  is.na(df$variable) = "fem"

Comment: Surely this has been asked and answered?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `ppp$female <- "fem"` will work fine. As per the comments, more general approaches (e.g., when you have `NA`s mixed with other values) might be more broadly helpful.